# Adding a confidence value for each field in a django model

Tags: python, django

Imagine a django model like a Building:

```
class Building(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField('address')
    age = models.IntegerField('age')
```

I want to have a confidence value for each of these fields e.g. I am 90% sure that the address is "768 5th Ave, New York", but 100% sure that the building is 30 years old. Would be great to use tuples for instantiation and have a confidence value set for each field:

```
>>> b = Building(
      address=("768 5th Ave, New York", 0.9),
      age=(34, 1.0))
>>> b.address
'768 5th Ave, New York'
>>> b.address.confidence
0.9
```

or maybe at least something like this:

```
>>> b.confidences['address']
0.9
```

I want to apply the confidence value to all my current django models, so I am looking for the most elegant and generic way of doing this hopefully with least amount of changes to the model definitions I already have. obviously below is very hard to do...

```
class Building(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField('address')
    address_confidence = models.FloatField('address_confidence')

    age = models.IntegerField('age')
    age_confidence = models.FloatField('age_confidence')
```

Some of the things I can think of but not sure:

- having a base model that creates a confidence value for each field (maybe during **init**) and then making that as the base of all my models instead of models.Model?
- creating a custom field which has confidence value and takes care of how it should be treated when reading/writing to database?
- Having another model with a confidence field and using ForeignKey to link to that?

Thank you,
H

Comment: for the instantiating with tuple part you could just create a set_address method

Comment: What database backend are you using?

Comment: How about this - create a `BaseClass` whose `save()` method adds a field called `name_confidence = models.FloatField` for every field declared in the inherited model? Additionally, you can also call `name_calculate_confidence` as a class method on the inherited class to calculate the confidence for that field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest Django and Postgres as a backend, you could use a [HStoreField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield). Which would allow you to store data in the form of a python dict()

```
{'address': '768 5th Ave, New York', 'confidence': 0.9}
```

It is a single field in the db but with tremendous flexibility

The other option is an [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield). But you could not label the values like you could an HStoreField.

**This is only functional if your backend is Postgres**

Comment: Thank you very much! I am using MySQL but can change to Postgres if that will help... however, it seems like HStoreField can only take string to string dicts... I need to be able to do this on any kind of models.Field ...

ArrayField also seems to only be able to create arrays when they are of the same field... for me I need two value, the first one can be any Field, the second one is a float value for confidence.

Comment: The only other thing I could think of using a custom model field that may save the data in a charfield with the data in save in pipe `|` delimited form. ie. `768 5th Ave, New York|0.9` - and the custom field would save and read the values for you... that would be database independent and would not require a foreignkey

Answer (score 0):

In you situation, i think explicit field is better.

> having a base model that creates a confidence value for each field (maybe during init) and then making that as the base of all my models instead of models.Model

this is not good idea, because you can't know all field in a glance by the model.

> Having another model with a confidence field and using ForeignKey to link to that

this method is heavy. you must create a new table, and the confident is one-to-one relation with adress and age, create new table is not standard.And when you delete one record, you must condider the other table.

> creating a custom field which has confidence value and takes care of how it should be treated when reading/writing to database

this is better method.

Answer (score -1):

You could subclass CharField and IntegerField to add a confidence property to them, or even create your own model field, like:

```
class CharConfidenceField(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    confidence = model.IntegerField()
```

The django documentation shows how to create your own model field here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-model-fields/

Comment: This creates a new model, not a new field.